# where is IgnoreRoute for *.config files?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-config, ignoreroute

there is no IgnoreRoute for *.config files but I can't request for web.config or other files that has .config extension.

where exactly this restriction defined?

Answer (score 0):

This is restricted in IIS by default.
This is due to security because connection string and application specific information is usually stored in the web.config file.